# How do I use and implement getModuleDir to echo view directory in template file?

Tags: magento-2.1, template

I'd like to use getModuleDir to get my module's view directory and use it in my template file.
Which file do I add the getModuleDir function to, and how do I call this function in my template?

- Vendor = Martens
- Module = Showroom
- Template = showroom.phtml

I have this code but do not know how to use or alter it...

```
class CustomModel
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader
 */
protected $moduleReader;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
) {
    $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
}

public function getDirectory()
{
    $viewDir = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir::MODULE_VIEW_DIR,
        'Vendor_Module'
    );
    return $viewDir . '/frontend/web/images';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with FileSystem(\Magento\Framework\Filesystem):

```
class CustomModel
   {
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem
     */
     protected $moduleReader;

     /**
      * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $moduleReader
      */
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $moduleReader
     ) {
         $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
     }

     public function getDirectory()
    {
         $viewDir = $this->moduleReader->getDirectoryRead(
             \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir::MODULE_VIEW_DIR,
             'Vendor_Module'
         );
         return $viewDir . '/frontend/web/images';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't answer my question. Which file holds this code and how do I use it in my template file?

Comment: Where do I put this code? In which file or folder?

Comment: put this code into your custom class

Comment: As in "Namespace\Module\Model\MyClass.php" ?

Comment: no in block file which you used for your template

Comment: ok thank you. And how do I use/call this in my template? <?php echo $this->moduleReader->getDirectoryRead('frontend/web/images') ???

Comment: you can create a function in your block which returns image path then you can call that function